# Data type mismatch in criteria expression error in cascading combobox

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2007

I'm getting a "data type mismatch in criteria expression" error every time on a form I have set up in my database with cascading comboboxes from two different tables: **tblUnits** and **tblProjects**.  The first combobox (cboUnit) selects the appropriate UnitID from **tblUnits**, while the second (cboProject) limits options to ProjectID's to the selected UnitID.

RowSource for cboUnit:

```
SELECT [tblUnits].ID, [tblUnits].Unit FROM tblUnits ORDER BY [Unit];
```

And here's the code for the AfterUpdate:

```
Private Sub cboUnit_AfterUpdate()
     On Error Resume Next
     cboProject.RowSource = "Select tblProjects.ID " & _
                          "FROM tblProjects " & _ 
                          "WHERE tblProjects.UnitID = '" & cboUnit.Value & _ 
                          "ORDER BY tblProjects.ID;"
```

The ProjectID and UnitID fields in the destination table are numeric but are NOT lookup fields, and the bound columns are correct.  I don't understand why I keep getting the criteria mismatch even when dealing strictly with the foreign keys.

Comment: the quote in the WHERE clause has to be deleted and a blank is needed in front of `ORDER` ! Check with `debug.print cboUnit.Value` if `cboUnit`is bound to `UnitID`.

Comment: Thanks much! Just caught that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Christopher explained how to cure the error from the `SELECT` statement the code builds.

However, I don't think you should need to modify `cboProject.RowSource` every time the user selects a value in `cboUnit`.

It should be simpler to use this for `cboProject.RowSource`, and don't change it afterward:

```sql
SELECT p.ID FROM tblProjects AS p
WHERE p.UnitID = [Forms]![YourFormNameHere]![cboUnit]
ORDER BY p.ID;
```

Then all you need to do for `cboUnit` *After Update* is requery `cboProject`:

```vb
Private Sub cboUnit_AfterUpdate()
    Me!cboProject.Requery
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an orphaned single quote where you're dropping the cboUnit value. Assuming that both fields are autonumbers (or long ints), just delete the single quote:

```
Private Sub cboUnit_AfterUpdate()
 On Error Resume Next
 cboProject.RowSource = "Select tblProjects.ID " & _
                      "FROM tblProjects " & _ 
                      "WHERE tblProjects.UnitID = " & cboUnit.Value & _ 
                      " ORDER BY tblProjects.ID;"
```